# Fetch data from different APIs through the same struct?

Tags: swift, api, struct

Is it possible to fetch data from different but similar APIs (different URLs but similar JSON construction) through the same structure?

For example accessing data with `bitcoinUSD.raw.eth.usd.price` and `bitcoinUSD.raw.eth.gbp.price` through:

```
struct Bitcoin : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case raw = "RAW" }
    let raw : BitcoinRAW
}

struct BitcoinRAW : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case btc = "BTC" }
    let btc : BitcoinETH
}

struct BitcoinETH : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case usd = "USD"
        case gbp = "GBP"
    }
    let usd : BitcoinUSD
    let gbp : BitcoinGBP
}

struct BitcoinUSD : Decodable {
    let price : Double
    let percentChange24h : Double

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case price = "PRICE"
        case percentChange24h = "CHANGEPCT24HOUR"
    }
}

struct BitcoinGBP : Decodable {
    let price : Double
    let percentChange24h : Double

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case price = "PRICE"
        case percentChange24h = "CHANGEPCT24HOUR"
    }
}
```

Here are my data fetching functions:

```
enum MyErrorBTC : Error {
    case FoundNil(String)
}

class BitcoinInfo : NSObject {

    static var btcURL : URL?

    func fetchBitcoinInfo(completion: @escaping (Bitcoin?, Error?) -> Void) {

        if WalletViewController.currencyUSD == true {
            BitcoinInfo.btcURL = URL(string: "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD")!
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: BitcoinInfo.btcURL!) { (data, response, error) in
                guard let data = data else { return }
                do {
                    if let bitcoinPrice = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Bitcoin.self, from: data) {
                        completion(bitcoinPrice, nil)
                        //print("price =", bitcoinUSD.raw.btc.usd.price)
                        throw MyErrorBTC.FoundNil("bitcoinPrice")
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        } else if WalletViewController.currencyGBP == true {
            BitcoinInfo.btcURL = URL(string: "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=GBP")!
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: BitcoinInfo.btcURL!) { (data, response, error) in
                guard let data = data else { return }
                do {
                    if let bitcoinPrice = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Bitcoin.self, from: data) {
                        completion(bitcoinPrice, nil)
                        //print("price =", bitcoinUSD.raw.btc.gbp.price)
                        throw MyErrorBTC.FoundNil("bitcoinPrice")
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Please note this code returns nil when either functions are called.
Is there any way to modify it?

Comment: Show your API fetch functions so people can provide feedback.

Comment: @creeperspeak I edited my question with the full code

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to make your fetch function more reusable, it seems like the only difference between the 2 endpoints is the currency.  In that case, why not just pass the currency in as an argument, and build your URL with the currency argument you get.  That would look like this:

```
func fetchBitcoinInfo(forCurrency currency: String, _ completion: @escaping (Bitcoin?, Error?) -> Void) {
    BitcoinInfo.btcURL = URL(string: "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=\(currency)")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: BitcoinInfo.ethURL!) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            if let bitcoinPrice = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Bitcoin.self, from: data) {
                completion(bitcoinPrice, nil)
            } else {
                throw MyErrorBTC.FoundNil("bitcoinPrice")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

As an aside, you were throwing `FoundNil` when you *were* getting a valid `Bitcoin` object back, which didn't make sense.  I moved your error throw into an `else` statement so that it only throws when your `bitcoinPrice` unwrap fails.

Comment: Thanks a lot Creeper! This is an amazing solution, I didn't know you could alter the URL! What about the `struct` now? How will I be able to access `bitcoinUSD.raw.eth.usd.price` and `bitcoinUSD.raw.eth.gbp.price` depending on the choosen currency?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you should declare your variables as optional:

```
struct BitcoinETH : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case usd = "USD"
        case gbp = "GBP"
    }
    let usd : BitcoinUSD?
    let gbp : BitcoinGBP?
}
```

If not, exception will be thrown and you'll get nil value for whole structure as it will not be decoded as decoder expected it to be

Comment: Thank you very much Eugene, I tried this solution without success but I'm sure I must try to access the data the wrong way.

Comment: @Martin33000 can you tell me, why didn't you get success with this approach? Because i did ) If you'll use optional values, this structure will be decoded in the correct way, for example, if you'll use tsyms=USD, only usd will be decoded and gbp will be nil, if you'll use tsyms=GBP, then structure will be also decoded correctly with filled gbp value and usd will be nil. If you'll try GBP,USD the both will be filled correctly, and with other types both will be nil

Comment: How did you access the data in that case? When I try `print("price =", bitcoinPrice.raw.btc.gbp.price)` inside `func fetchBitcoinInfo` it doesn't even print

Comment: @Martin3300 Well, first of all i've changed structure as i've shown in answer, and second, you have few typos in code:
1. use print("price = \\(String(describing: bitcoinPrice.raw.btc.usd?.price))")
2. move throw statement to else

Comment: Okay 1. I changed the `print`, 2. moved the throw to else and 3. modify the struct to declare variables as optionals. I am still getting `FoundNil("bitcoinPrice")`

Comment: @Martin33000 I've made a very simple project with your structures, you'll see result in debugger window, after app will launch: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jify0fqhsxps7gs/netnetnet.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thank you so much Eugene, your project works very well indeed! I will use it to fix mine

Comment: No problemo )))